# Will chained GFCIs malfunction?

Tags: wiring, gfci

What I'm asking is if a GFCI wired onto the load of another GFCI will function?   Will it cause the upstream one to malfunction.  Will it cause the downstream one to malfunction?   It is against code?

I know I will inevitably get responses telling me there's no reason to do this or that I don't understand how to wire a GFCI.   This is not what I'm asking.

(Basically the reason is that it will allow be more flexibility to switch which circuit an outdoor outlet is wired into.   I will have access to a circuit for the garage (GFCI'ed) and circuit for a bedroom (AFCI'ed).   Using the GFCI protected circuit form the garage just seems easiest because it will therefore also protect some other outdoor lights.   But I don't know if the inspector is going to take issue with an outlet and a couple lights on the garage circuit but not in the garage.   If I just put an additional GFCI on the outdoor outlet, I think it is less likely to cause issues, and if it does, I can easily move it to the other circuit.)

Comment: Call up the inspector and ask. If you use the garage circuit and put the little "GFCI protected" stickers on the outdoor outlet(s), and it trips when or if the inspector chooses to put a GFCI tester into it, there should be no issue - but it's always easiest and most efficient just to ask before you cobble something up, so you can just put in what the inspector wants the first time, rather than having to do it twice.

Comment: @Ecnerwal:   The sticking point is whether I really want to draw attention to the fact that the outdoor outlet is on the garage circuit.   Obviously it is fine from a safely point of view, but inspectors are unpredictable.   If I do what you say, we will trip the GFCI and then I will have to go into the garage and reset it.    I basically trying to protect myself against a difficult inspector.   If call him will still draw attention to the question and make my life more difficult.

Comment: On the contrary - if you call him he'll either say "don't connect it to the garage" or "makes no difference to me". If you connect it to the garage, and he has an objection to that, you are going to be far worse off if you've already done that, than if you ask first, and don't do that. Playing games is far more likely to tick off an inspector than asking questions; but suit yourself.

Comment: I don’t know about regulations (and you didn’t say where you are anyway), but there is no technical or safety reason it shouldn’t work. Obviously, if your power goes away, you won’t know which of the breakers tripped, but that should not be too hard to find out.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, contacting the inspector is the best way to determine what they expect.  As for which circuit to install an outdoor receptacle on, I'd go with the garage circuit. It's already GFCI protected, and in my mind makes more sense on a garage circuit than a bedroom circuit.